# How to distribute a GtkAda application under Windows?

Tags: ada, software-distribution, gnat-gps, gtkada

I'm having troubles distributing a GtkAda application on Windows. I made an executable (with Windows native compiler) and tried using it on another Windows computer. However, I get errors about dlls missing.

I tried distributing with my .exe three folders.

- `bin` including the dlls installed by GtkAda,
- `etc` including `fonts`, `gtk-3.0` and `pango`,
- `lib` including `gtk-3.0` with dlls too.

This is what I read from the [GtkAda documentation](https://docs.adacore.com/gtkada-docs/gtkada_ug/_build/html/getting_started.html#how-to-distribute-a-gtkada-application)

I think I maybe forgot to specify something in the project file

Here my GPS project file

```
with "C:\GNAT\GTK\lib\gnat\gtkada";

project Logfilter is
    for Source_Dirs use ("src");
    for Object_Dir  use "obj";
    for Exec_Dir    use "exec";
    for Main use ("log_filter_main.adb");

    package Builder is
      for Executable ("main.adb") use "Logs_Filter";
    end Builder;

    package Compiler is
      for Switches ("ada") use ("-Wl,--subsystem,windows");
    end Compiler;

end Logfilter;
```

I'm using a glade (gtk 3.14) file and GtkAda 2019.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible you're missing libgnat and/or libgnarl ? Anyways, you need to know which DLL is missding (_dependancy walker_ maybe useful ?)

Comment: All the missing libraries are in my bin folder. My executable is in the application root folder. It is in the same folder than the three folders I listed above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you put the main executable (`log_filter_main.exe`)? What libraries are missing?

When I create a directory structure using the batch program below (change the variables `GTKADA_INSTALL_DIR` and `TARGET_DIR` to match your situation), and then copy my executable (a simple GtkAda program) into `%TARGET_DIR%\bin`, then this executable runs just fine. It's important that the application resides in the `bin` folder such that the correct GTK runtime libraries will be found during startup.

**create_standalone.bat**

```
SET GTKADA_INSTALL_DIR=C:\GNAT\2019\GtkAda
SET TARGET_DIR=C:\Test

xcopy /s /i %GTKADA_INSTALL_DIR%\bin\*.dll       %TARGET_DIR%\bin\
xcopy /s /i %GTKADA_INSTALL_DIR%\etc\*.*         %TARGET_DIR%\etc\
xcopy /s /i %GTKADA_INSTALL_DIR%\lib\gtk-3.0\*.* %TARGET_DIR%\lib\gtk-3.0\

REM  Copy your GtkAda application (.exe and other dependencies if applicable) 
REM  to %TARGET_DIR%\bin\
```

Regarding the project file: first, it's not completely clear why the `Builder` package is needed, but I might lack some project specific knowledge/requirements here. Second, if you want to get rid of the console window popping up when starting the GUI application, then you might want to use

```
package Linker is
  for Switches ("ada") use ("-mwindows");
end Linker;
```

instead of

```
package Compiler is
  for Switches ("ada") use ("-Wl,--subsystem,windows");
end Compiler;
```

*Note*:

Small additional note beyond the scope of the question (you may already have thought of it): please do not forget to quit the GTK main application when you close the main window. Define (for example):

```
procedure Destroy_Event_Callback
   (Widget : access Gtk.Widget.Gtk_Widget_Record'Class)
is
begin
   Gtk.Main.Main_Quit;
end Destroy_Event_Callback;
```

and then register it as a callback when the main window is initialized:

```
Main_Window.On_Destroy (Destroy_Event_Callback'Access);
```

If the `Gtk.Main.Main_Quit` call is omitted, then the program (process) will keep running after you close the main window (at least when you use the `-mwindows` linker option).

Comment: The problem was my .exe not being in bin with the dlls needed. Now I only need to get done with the `GLib-GIO-ERROR`strange error.